# Accessing second hard drive Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, windows-10, lts

On my device I have 2 hard drive one of which is partitioned and contain in one of the partitions both windows 10 and Ubuntu operating systems. When I boot into Ubuntu I can see the other hard drive and partition but cannot access them. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you use the `mount` command or the file explorer?

Comment: I had tried both

Answer (score 0):

You need to deactivate the fast start up function in windows under power options. Once you do that the drives become accessible on Ubuntu.