# Using Ubuntu, Assign second drive to be used by windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-10

I have a computer with two hard drives
One is partitioned, running Ubuntu, and windows **ON TOP OF UBUNTU**.
The second drive is empty
Ubuntu recognized the second drive, and has access to it
Windows does not

How can I make the second drive available for windows to use?

I have the opposite problem of this question:
[Accessing second hard drive Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894722/accessing-second-hard-drive-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: I found the answer

Comment: I found the answer, windows will recognize the drive in the Device Manager, but will not let you write to it until you go to computer management. From start, search 'Computer Management. Then click on Disk Management, click on the drive you want. There should be boxes at the bottom half of the window showing the disk capacity and their partitions. The one that is not being used will say 'Unallocated'. Right click on it and select "New Simple Volume" then go through setting it up with the prompts windows gives you

Comment: Post your answer as **an answer** and not as a comment - that it not what the comments are for.

Comment: i cant, i dont have enough points

Comment: You can answer ***any*** question (including your own question) with 1 point see https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, windows will recognize the drive in the Device Manager, but will not let you write to it until you go to computer management. From start, search 'Computer Management. Then click on Disk Management, click on the drive you want. There should be boxes at the bottom half of the window showing the disk capacity and their partitions. The one that is not being used will say 'Unallocated'. Right click on it and select "New Simple Volume" then go through setting it up with the prompts windows gives you